# data truncated to 255 characters using excel Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: .net, excel

Other than registry change, can we fix data truncated to 255 characters using excel Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to combat this is to insert a dummy data row underneath your header row.  You can then add some 'lorem ipsum' or similar text that exceeds 255 characters in every column where you need more text.  The ADO.NET provider (ACE in this case) should then scan the first few rows and realise that more than 255 characters are required.

I'd be interested to hear if you find a better way!

Comment: @Priya: did you have any luck in the end?